# What should we do about group questions?

Tags: discussion

I feel like we should discourage group questions somehow. We typically mark them invalid in the tracker and make people break them up. The reasoning is:

- It requires vague or long titles. If your question is multi-part, the title probably doesn't accurately cover the contents of your post.
- It requires more effort on the part of responses. It's very possible that the person responding only knows the answer to one of those questions.
- It means questions can be marked as "answered" even if they contain unanswered parts.

Comment: Yep, came across several of this in the last hour.

Comment: Also it reduces reusability of Q&As, so it makes it harder to link them from elsewhere.

Comment: Break them up, or slim down into one question and file the others elsewhere. I'm fairly certain that stackexchange has this in the guidelines somewhere.

Comment: Is this one of such questions? http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/29/84

Comment: @waldyrious I would say, yes

Comment: Ok, I split the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Group questions are discouraged across the whole Stack Exchange network.

This is a Q&A site, and for there to be Answers, there have to be Questions.

However, questions that don't have just one answer, don't work, there are a number of reasons, but primarily, it means *there is no one right answer*.

Typically, different people will know about and answer different things across the network, and if they only know the answer to one part of the question, one of two things happens.

1. They don't answer at all. This means the whole site has lost out on knowledge, and puts the site at a disadvantage for people from Google.
2. They answer the half question. This is better than 1. but still not idea. It means it probably can't be accepted and it looks "unsolved" forever.

Note that there is a line. Someone might have 2 closely related questions, for example they are trying to do one thing (e.g. can't delete a file) and there are two issues stopping them, (e.g. Can't select a file and can't find trash). Use your judgement for that.

#### So what do we do?

1. First, comment. Ask the person to split it up and see if they comply. Give them a couple of days.
2. Then close it. It would be nice to edit it yourself to remove one of them, but that will annoy them even more. And you can't repost their question, because you (the OP) can't answer the questions asked of them.

   Closing is the right option. Too broad covers this - there is no need for a custom close message.