# Is installing the elementary Suite on another OS on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Is installing and working with the elementary Suite (Gala, Files, Image Viewer, Cerbere, etc.) on another OS (e.g. Arch Linux) on-topic here?

Can I ask a question about using elementary packages not in an official elementary installation?
Or would that belong on Unix.SE?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm talking about questions like "How to resolve some problem with Gala on Arch?".  Which it sounds like are off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, seeing as this is the elementary OS Stack Exchange, rather than the elementary Stack Exchange, that such questions would indeed belong on Unix.SE, with the possible exception of Ubuntu questions belonging on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Did the team chose `elementaryos.SE` name or did StackExchange chose it? It seems to me like SE chose it. I _think_ that the team would go with `elementary.SE`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe **it depends on the nature of the question**:

If the question is **generic**, and the problem faced would be the same on an elementary installation as well as one with just the elementary suite, it should be on-topic. Examples of this include [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/755/how-can-i-test-the-new-indicators) and [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/735/how-do-i-change-the-keyboard-layout).

On the other hand, if it pertains to a **compatibility issue**, or otherwise wouldn't affect a normal elementary installation, it should be off-topic.